# How to identity if when was PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT changed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

We are using oracle 19c
, Recently we had altered the PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT value  TO 20GB but after a week we see that it is 10GB
Is there a way to check when was this altered .

Regards
Tejas

Comment: try looking into dba_hist_parameter, it will give you a rough idea. You may also look into your alert.log file if you have access to the server.